# « C'est vous qui décidez » ou « c'est vous qui décide » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, conjugaison, pronoms-relatifs, pronoms-personnels

Je voudrais savoir si après le mot *qui* on doit utiliser le singulier ou le pluriel.

Par exemple

> C'est vous qui décidez.

ou bien

> C'est vous qui décide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le *qui* ne change pas la conjugaison : on accorde toujours le verbe par rapport au sujet.

> C'est moi qui décide.
>   C'est nous qui décidons.
>   C'est vous qui décidez.

etc.

Answer (score 3):

Le sujet du verbe *décider* est le pronom relatif *qui*. Le verbe s'accorde avec l'antécédent du pronom, aussi bien pour le nombre (singulier ou pluriel) que pour la personne.

> C'est **vous** qui décid**ez**.
>   C'est **elle** qui est parti**e**.

Il en est de même lorsque le pronom relatif est complément d'objet direct, qui peut entraîner un accord avec le participe passé si le verbe de la subordonnée est à un temps composé avec l'auxiliaire *avoir*.

> C'est **elle** que j'ai vu**e** hier.

Il en est aussi de même lorsque la proposition principale est autre chose que « c'est » + pronom.

> **Vous** qui **êtes** plus rapides, commencez la deuxième partie.

En fait, le cas où l'antécédent du pronom relatif est un pronom personnel est simplement un cas particulier. On accorde le verbe de la proposition relative suivant l'antécédent du pronom dans tous les cas.

> **La personne** qui est parti**e** a oublié son chapeau.
>   **La décision** que j'ai pris**e** était la bonne.