# Lorsqu'on s'adresse à quelqu'un, quelle conjugaison utilise-on dans les propositions relatives?

Tags: verbes, accord, conjugaison, pronoms-relatifs

Dans le poème "Chanson" de la première partie de "Les Chansons de Bilitis", Pierre Louÿs écrit:

> Beau fleuve qui l'as vue passer, dis-moi, est-elle près d'ici?

Ici, la narratrice, Bilitis, tutoie le fleuve. Le *elle* est la maîtrise de Bilitis. Pourquoi dit-on du fleuve *qui l'as vue passer*, non *qui l'a vue passer*? Si l'on s'adresse à quelqu'un et il y a une proposition relative pour cet objet, utilise-on une conjugaison de la deuxième personne au lieu d'une conjugaison de la troisième personne? (En anglais, on utilise une conjugaison de la troisième personne. Par exemple, on dit *Blessed are You … who has sanctified us*, non *Blessed are You … who have sanctified us*.)

Comment: As usual: I'm not a native speaker, so feel free to make any corrections to grammar / usage mistakes.

Comment: This is a great but common question with previous answers, such as [this one](http://ow.ly/Jyjj30c8MWP) and [this one](http://ow.ly/KMzs30c8MXb). Granted these aren't exact matches, so to bridge the gap: Yes, there's an implicit *toi* there — i.e. "Beau fleuve" is in the same grammatical case ([vocative](http://ow.ly/18eA30c8N1g)) as "Toi" — and "Toi qui [verbe]" will have the verb conjugated for *tu*. Also, in English you can say "You who've caused so much trouble, will you please leave?" I wonder if the "blessed" and "sanctified" of your example might not signal an older tendency.

Comment: @LukeSawczak: Good point; I'm not quite sure about the English now. (I can think of some cases where a conjugation in conformation with _you_ is used &mdash; for instance _you who kill prophets_, which, contrary to what I previously thought, apparently takes on singular and not plural _you_.)

Comment: More precisely, it takes on *you* instead of *he*, since *you* is conjugated with "have" no matter the number: "You have caused, you have killed, you have sanctified." In older English, we'd be able to distinguish plurality: "Thou who hast sanctified" and not "Thou who have sanctified". Back to the original question, this were an English forum I'd do more research into "Thou who *has* sanctified". Is it as normal as or even preferred over "Thou who hast"? Both are attested in Google results but require much sifting. Hmm...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Not really dupes, why not turn it into an answer?

Comment: s'adresser not adresser.

Comment: @Lambie: oops, thanks for the correction; it occurs to me that passive voice constructions don't work as well with indirect objects. I'll try to find another way to word that...

Comment: @Maroon Lorsqu'on s'adresse à quelqu'un. :)

Comment: @Lambie: Thanks! Hopefully this reads better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the verb uses the *tu* form because *beau fleuve* is in the second person.

One might be sceptical of that observation, because we know that inanimate objects are generally in the third person, since they can neither speak nor be spoken to. But then you have poetry. :)

The second person is associated with [the vocative case](http://ow.ly/18eA30c8N1g), which is the form of a noun you use when you're addressing it. Latin had an explicit vocative case, meaning the noun changed form depending on whether it was being referred to (nominative) or addressed (vocative).

Although French stopped marking the vocative case visibly in noun endings, it can still give hints, such as using the particle *Ô* as in *Ô Canada* (or Alice in Wonderland's delightful ["O mouse!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland))).

However, whether or not that helpful particle is attached, we should assume that every noun is cased, *even when the case is invisible*. For the same reason, we assume every noun has a person, gender, and number even when these features are invisible, and are instead marked by [null morphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_morpheme).

So if there is an invisible morpheme for vocative case, how do we know that our *beau fleuve* has it? The rest of the sentence provides a couple of clues (note that unlike *a* / *as*, these ones are audible):

1. The *narratrice* omits the article before *beau fleuve*.<sup>1</sup> As a cautionary note, though, we should be careful about reading as much into the absence of articles in poetry as we would in prose.
2. She issues an imperative to the river. An imperative can only be issued in the second person.<sup>2</sup>

Because of these two things, we can be sure she's addressing the river, which means it's in vocative case, which means it's in second person.

Once we've established that, we can refer to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/549/moi-qui-fait-ou-moi-qui-fais?rq=1) and [this one](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7580/cest-vous-qui-d%C3%A9cidez-ou-cest-vous-qui-d%C3%A9cide?noredirect=1&lq=1) to establish that *toi* and not *qui* determines the conjugation for *avoir*.

<sup><sub>1 – While the absence of an article is usually *sufficient* to show vocative case, it's not *necessary*, since one can say things like  "Salut, les enfants !"</sub></sup>

<sup><sub>2 – Even though French grammarians also call the [cohortative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hortative#Cohortative) an "imperative" for whatever reason.</sub></sup>

---

Incidentally, the idea of invisible morphemes are not without controversy. Here are a couple of other questions they raise:

1. You'd expect English to be heavily cased, being a Germanic language. But it only marks nominative/accusative case and only on four personal pronouns: *I / me* ; *he / him* ; *she / her* ; *we / us*. However, the existence of these pairs begs the question: does English track case invisibly on all nouns, or does it casually bring in the linguistic feature of case just for eight words? Neither theory is very appealling.
2. Are all French nouns in the vocative case marked for formality? Imagine I address someone: "Bonjour, Alex." If my next utterance is "Comment allez-vous ?", does the `+formal` feature appear only then, or is it just agreement with an invisible `+formal` feature present on *Alex* ? If that seems far-fetched, consider that if I use an adjective, it might well be `+feminine`, and we know it's not because the adjective is inherently feminine but because it responds to the person.

Hence, not only do we have to suppose that *beau fleuve* is invisibly vocative... we have to suppose that it's invisibly *toi*, as you noted, rather than *vous* !

Comment: Thanks: I was mostly concerned with the issue covered in the semi-dupe, but it was nice to see the grammar parsed out; I hadn't quite thought of it that way.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, hopefully it's a nice reference for whoever wants it :)

Answer (score 2):

Très bonne question ! Beaucoup de Français commettent des fautes dans ce genre de phrase. La narratrice s'adresse donc au fleuve.

Lorsque l'on a un doute, il suffit de mettre le sujet au pluriel :

– Beaux fleuves qui l'avez vue passer, dites-moi, est-elle près d'ici ?

Cela sonne très bien à l'oreille ! Au singulier comme au pluriel, donc, on utilisera la deuxième personne.

(En revanche, « Beaux fleuves qui l'ont vue passer, dites-moi, est-elle… » serait catastrophique.)

Euh ! J’ai écrit un article à ce sujet… Je vous en donne le lien : http://unmondesansfautes.blogspot.fr/2016/03/mes-verbes-au-festival-de-fautesville_22.html

Comment: C'est vrai, essayer une conjugaison qui se prononce différement révèle souvent la fiabilité de l'instinct.