# La grammaire du Notre Père

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, vouvoiement

Ma question concerne le Notre Père en français.

D'abord, « qui **es** aux cieux ». Pourquoi n'est-ce pas « qui **est** aux cieux » ? Je pense que c'est à cause du Latin « qui es in caelis » mais je sais pas.

Deuxièmement, quand **les cieux** est mentionné la seconde fois, pourquoi n'est-ce pas au pluriel ? C'est le même concept, non?

Finalement, « **donne**-nous » et « **pardonne**-nous » me paraissent bizarres : « donne » est la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du singulier (non ?), mais je pensais que c’était adressé à Dieu, alors, « **donnez**-nous ». De plus, pourquoi pas « **nous**-donnez » ? J’ai l’impression que l’objet direct va avant le verbe…

Merci beaucoup, j’espère que mon français est compréhensible… mon niveau n’est que B1, mais je voudrais C2 (éventuellement).

Comment: Pour la première question, il vaut bien lire des questions comme [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7580/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Avant 1966, on disait le Notre Père soit en latin, soit en français en vouvoyant Dieu :

> *Notre Père qui **êtes** aux cieux, que **votre** Nom...*

A partir de 1966 (Concile Vatican II), le Latin est abandonné et on tutoie Dieu :

> *Notre Père qui **es** aux cieux, que **ton** Nom...*

La deuxième personne est utilisée car la prière s'adresse à Dieu, précédemment au pluriel (vous de respect) :

> *Notre Père[, **vous**] qui **êtes** aux cieux*

puis au singulier (retour au tutoiement original) :

> Notre Père[, **toi**] qui **es** aux cieux*.

Le vouvoiement de respect n'existait pas en latin.

On peut aussi remarquer que le tutoiement a totalement disparu en anglais **sauf** dans des textes liturgiques où l'on s'adresse à Dieu :

> Our Father, which **art** in heaven, hallowed be **thy** Name...

D'autre part, ***donne-nous*** n'est pas une troisième personne mais une deuxième personne du singulier.

En effet, le ***s*** final de la deuxième personne du singulier que l'on trouve à l'indicatif est absent à l'impératif des verbes du premier groupe ainsi que quelques verbes du troisième groupe.

***Aux cieux*** est au pluriel comme en latin, mais au singulier dans la version la plus ancienne rédigée grec. On retrouve aussi le singulier dans une prière similaire en hébreu. Le mot *ciel* a deux pluriels en français. *ciels* qui est régulier et *cieux* qui est plus emphatique. Ce pluriel fait ici référence soit aux sphères célestes imbriquées de la cosmologie de l'antiquité (planètes, firmament, septième ciel) soit à la hiérarchie céleste de la théologie chrétienne. ***Au ciel, au Paradis*** pourrait être utilisé en français moderne (la version anglaise dit *in heaven* pas *in the heavens*).

Comment: _Cieux_ au pluriel fait référence à la [hiérarchie céleste](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hi%C3%A9rarchie_c%C3%A9leste) de la théologie chrétienne.

Comment: Relativement à l'observation faite au sujet du *s* final de la 2p imp. Dans la mesure ou suit un autre impératif à la 2p imp. (*ne nous soumet**s***) qui lui évidemment garde son *s*, j'aurais précisé dans cette note : *pour les verbes du premier groupe de conjugaison*

Comment: @aCOSωτ C'est fait, merci !